# Should this Chef recipe be refactored?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've written a recipe that installs Windows desktop apps from a databag:

```
workstation_apps = data_bag_item('winapps','desktop_apps')

for package in workstation_apps['apps'] do
        chocolatey_package "#{package}" do
        action :install
        end
end
```

Running foodcritic I get an error:

```
FC002: Avoid string interpolation where not required: ./recipes/default.rb:23
```

As you can see, I added double quotes around #{package} so that it expands the variable and does not function as a comment.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things: first the use of `for` loops in Ruby is discouraged in favor of `each` loops. Second, the chocolatey package provider support multi-package operations so you can rewrite the recipe like this:

```
workstation_apps = data_bag_item('winapps','desktop_apps')
chocolatey_package workstation_apps['apps']
```

(remember that `:install` is the default action so you don't need to write it out)

Comment: Ah ok! Well I guess it's time to refactor again :)

Comment: For bonus points this will also be much faster as it will run all the installs in a single chocolatey install command.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `"#{package}"` to `package.to_s`.
If `package` is a string object, simply `package`:

```
workstation_apps = data_bag_item('winapps','desktop_apps')

for package in workstation_apps['apps'] do
        chocolatey_package package do
                action :install
        end
end
```

Indented `action ...` line to make it clear that the line belong to a block.

Comment: Exactly, you should only use `package`.

Comment: @StephenKing, I modifed the code in the answer to exclude `.to_s`. Thank you for the feedback.